# Bash script to set an environment variable if unset

Tags: bash, shell, environment-variables

I wrote a bash script to set the environment variable `VAR` if it is currently not set:

example.sh

```bash
#!/bin/bash

if [ -z $VAR ]; then
    export VAR=abc
fi
```

Now I type this in the command line: `./example.sh && echo $VAR`. I expect `abc`, but the result is blank. Why?

Comment: You must run it as `source ./example.sh && echo $VAR`. Your command sets the environment variable within the context of `example.sh` script (which runs in a subshell): this cannot affect the parent environment.

Comment: As an aside, you must quote your variable to prevent globbing and word splitting: `[ -z "$VAR" ]` and `echo "$VAR"`.

Answer (score 2):

Use `source example.sh` or `. example.sh`